# Does BigQuery support or is it efficient writing parallelly to same table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

My job's workflow will run multiple jobs and all these jobs will try to insert data into the same table, probably at the same time.

1. Does this approach sound correct?
2. Can BigQuery handle writing parallelly on same table?
3. What will be bigquery works on these scenarios?

Concentrate on only write part (not reading part).

Answer (score 0):

Appends should have no issue, regardless of whether they're load jobs or streaming inserts.  It's actually very common.

If you're planning on modifying data already present in the table, that will require more consideration.  Things like DML modifications will fail in the presence of changing data while said query is running.

A read (SELECT query or reading rows directly) leverages a snapshot isolation mechanism, so it uses the state of the table at the time the reading starts to achieve a consistent view of the data.  Data arriving while the query is progressing are not observed by the query.